# 05 WRX: Front passenger caliper seizes every 11 months

Tags: brakes, subaru, brake-calipers, wrx

My front passenger caliper has seized up again today for the third time in two years. I noticed some increasing vibration in the steering wheel and a smell of burn while driving and pulled over to inspect the front end of the car. The right front caliper was burning hot and smelled like overheated brakes. The car had been driven for about 30 minutes in the city and light highway driving. I started to notice the increasing vibration on the highway. All failures happened in wet weather. The two previous failures were repaired with new calipers, rotors and pads. Could this failure be caused by something else than a bad caliper? These failures always seem to happen at 11 months interval and coincide with the arrival of the rainy season of the pacific northwest.

Comment: Do you drive through puddles often?

Comment: Not that much. The car is garaged and generally only driven during weekends. It generally and does not see much water during late spring, summer and early fall. When the front calipers were replaced last winter it drove through snow and rain for most of winter to get us outside to play. There were no symptoms during that time. I tried scanning for codes and found nothing. The ABS light has never come on as well.

Answer (score 1):

Root cause is considered faulty caliper at this point. Caliper lasted 2 years and roughly 30 000km